# Kinetic energy vs. momentum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, energy-conservation, collision

I am confused about how the law of the conservation of (kinetic) energy and the law of conservation of momentum can both hold true.

If we observe a certain collision, then depending on the final velocities there might be a reduction in the total kinetic energy in the system. Where does the energy go?

Here's an example of a collision which exhibits a reduction in kinetic energy:

For simplificty let's suppose it's an elastic collision with no friction or heat change etc. Let's suppose a $1kg$ projectile at $10 m/s$ hits a stationary $10kg$ block and bounces back with $-5 m/s$.
According to the conservation of momentum we can calculate that the block will have a volocity of $1.5 m/s$.
However, the kinetic energy before is $.5mv^2 = .5*1*10^2=50J$, while the total kinetic energy at the end is $.5*1*5^2+.5*10*1.5^2=23.75J$.

Where did the $26.25J$ energy go?

Comment: Why do you assume that the projectile bounces back with -5m/s? Without doing the math: That assumption may be violating the constraint that you look at an elastic collision.

Comment: I have not done the math, but it is unusual that the final velocity of the projectile is given. The system becomes overrefined. So, I recommend that you setup the two equations (momentum and energy) and calculate the final velocities of the two bodies for the case of an elastic collision.

Comment: Alright, so if we leave out that final velocity, how would we compute it? Would we apply both laws then?

Comment: Yes, you setup both laws and calculate the velocities. How this is done is explained on MANY websites. The result for your case is that the projectile has the velocity $-90/11m/s$ after the collision.

Comment: You are right. I could have easily found that out from many websites after I understood that the given rebound velocity was overdefined.

Comment: Typically, when the momentum conservation law gives one answer and the energy conservation law gives another answer, then the initial assumptions might be wrong. These two laws are independently verified and trusted to always hold true, so possibly the assumed impact speed and exit speed are not correct. When these two laws are in conflict, then this is often the reason in my experience.

Comment: Hi Angelorf. Welcome to Phys.SE. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: @Qmechanic thanks, but I am not asking for the method with which to solve my problem; it is not a homework-like question. Perhaps the fact that there are numbers in there makes you associate with homework questions, but I do think the actual example helps to clarify the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $23.75J$ energy can't have gone anywhere. What this means is that your construction is impossible. If there is no friction, no deformation, etc, then in an elastic collision the projectile cannot bounce back with $5 m/s$. It must go faster. The exact speed you can solve for using exactly conservation of energy & momentum.

Comment: Conversely, if the collision was not elastic than some of the kinetic energy might have been converted into sound, heat and deformation of the bodies for example.

Answer (score 0):

Predicting the results of an elastic collision can be tricky. In 1D if you want to start with the conservation equations, rearrange the energy equation so that you have a difference of two squares on each side. Factor these; then divide by the momentum equation (also rearranged).  An approach which is quicker and easier to remember, but requires more care , is to convert the initial velocities to the center of mass system. In that system, the collision causes the velocity of each of the masses to be  reversed (relative to the center of mass). Then you convert back to the original system. This also works in two or three dimensions, but you are working with velocity vectors (which may not leave along the entry line) and you need to know something about the final state.